# How to combine multiple .pcd files into a single .pcd file which contains point cloud data (python)?

Tags: python, ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

There are suggestions available in online to use "laser_scan_assembler", but i have no idea how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the point clouds using the PCL library:

```cpp
typedef pcl::PointXYZ PointType;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointType> CloudType;

// Load the PCD files
CloudType::Ptr cloud1(new CloudType);
CloudType::Ptr cloud2(new CloudType);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile("cloud1.pcd", *cloud1);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile("cloud2.pcd", *cloud2);

// Put in one output cloud
CloudType::Ptr output(new CloudType);
*output += *cloud1;
*output += *cloud2;

// Save the output file
pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII("output.pcd", *output);
```

Note that this simply concats the points. The input clouds have to be in the same coordinate system, otherwise a registration is needed first.

You can also use the bash executable `pcl_concatenate_points_pcd` to concat multiple PCD files.